# Mac not setting routes on openconnect with vpnc-client

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, routing, cisco-vpn-client

I'm trying to connect to a VPN on my Mac, but for some reason routes aren't being set, even though they seem to be set by the vpnc-client script.

```
root@machost:/Users/username# cat .openconnect
authgroup=AUTHGROUPHERE
user=USERHERE
script=/usr/local/bin/vpnc-script
no-cert-check
#background
#passwd-on-stdin

root@machost:/Users/username# openconnect --config=.openconnect HOSTHERE
POST https://HOSTHERE/
Attempting to connect to server 1.1.1.1:443
SSL negotiation with HOSTHERE
Connected to HTTPS on HOSTHERE
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
POST https://HOSTHERE/
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
Password:
POST https://HOSTHERE/
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
Connect Banner:
|
| BANNER HERE
|

add host 1.1.1.1: gateway 10.10.10.254
link#11
add net 172.16.128.0: gateway 172.16.130.3
add net 172.16.0.0: gateway 172.16.130.3
add net 172.16.90.200: gateway 172.16.130.3
add net 172.16.50.200: gateway 172.16.130.3
Connected utun1 as 172.16.130.3, using SSL
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS0.9)-(RSA)-(AES-128-CBC)-(SHA1).

root@machost:/Users/username# ifconfig utun1
utun1: flags=8051 mtu 1406
        inet 172.16.130.3 --> 172.16.130.3 netmask 0xffffffff

root@machost:/Users/username# netstat -rn | grep utun1
default            link#13            UCSI            4        0   utun1
PUBIP              link#13            UHW3I           0       82   utun1    139
PUBIP              link#13            UHWIi           1       41   utun1
239.255.255.250    link#13            UHmW3I          0        4   utun1    102
```

If I try to manually add one, it just doesn't get added (and for some reason, the other routes disappeared):

```
root@machost:/Users/username# route -n add 172.16.128.0/24  -interface utun1
add net 172.16.128.0: gateway utun1

root@machost:/Users/username# netstat -rn | grep utun1
default            link#13            UCSI            2        0   utun1
239.255.255.250    link#13            UHmW3I          0       24   utun1     82
```

Comment: Consider moving this question to apple.stackexchange.com.